# UILabel frame size animation not working on ios8

Tags: ios, swift, animation

When animating UILabel frame size change it's working on iOS9 but not on iOS8 (on iOS8 it jump to final state instead animating). This problem disappear when using UIView or iOS9.

What can cause this problem? (You can see the project at https://github.com/IdoNave/UIlabelAnimation)

```
class MyView: UIView {

var progrssLabel: UILabel?

func startProgreesAnimation(from: CGFloat, duration: Double) {
    if progrssLabel == nil {
        progrssLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width * from, height: frame.height))
        progrssLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.addSubview(progrssLabel!)
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.progrssLabel!.frame = self.bounds
    }) { (finish) in
        print("ProgreesAnimation ended")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where exactly? It didn't solve the problem when adding it on MyView or in the viewController that call this animation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622424/how-do-i-animate-constraint-changes?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately it is not solving the problem :(

Comment: Do you want to create a progress bar?

Comment: Yes but i need to use UILabel since i have some text animations that happen on this view (text color change - progress bar with black text color while under this label there is label with same text but white text color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason and solution for this issue at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22224630/1105726 
Adding the label to other view and running the animation on the view solved the problem! (more details in the link)