# Decrease the width of a view with animation

Tags: ios, swift, animation

Hi all I am facing an strange issue . I want to increase the width of a view on click of a button with animation which is working fine in my case. The code I am using to increase the width is below-

```
    @IBAction func increaseWidth(_ sender: AnyObject) {

      UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options:
       [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {

            print("Animation function animateStuff() started!")

            let frmPlay : CGRect = self.nameLbl.frame
            let originXbutton = frmPlay.origin.x
            let originYbutton = frmPlay.origin.y
            let originWidthbutton = frmPlay.size.width
            let originHeightbutton = frmPlay.size.height

           self.nameLbl.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: originXbutton,y :originYbutton), size: CGSize(width: originWidthbutton+100, height: originHeightbutton))


        }, completion: { finished in

    })
}
```

But the code which is use by me not decreasing the width with animation.It is just decreasing the width.The code which is used by to decrease the width is below-

```
@IBAction func decreaseWidth(_ sender: AnyObject) {


    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options:
        [.allowUserInteraction], animations: {

            print("Animation function animateStuff() started!")

            let frmPlay : CGRect = self.nameLbl.frame
            let originXbutton = frmPlay.origin.x
            let originYbutton = frmPlay.origin.y
            let originWidthbutton = frmPlay.size.width
            let originHeightbutton = frmPlay.size.height

            // self.nameLbl.frame = frmPlay
            self.nameLbl.frame =  CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: originXbutton,y :originYbutton), size: CGSize(width: originWidthbutton-100, height: originHeightbutton))



        }, completion: { finished in

    })

}
```

Please help where I am going wrong.

Comment: check my update.let me know what you think....

Comment: interesting question, seems UILabel is a special elements that you can't do resize animation on it (http://stackoverflow.com/a/22224630/3869284). try to put it into a UIView and animate on that view.

Comment: @Jeo - Updated code also have same response as previous one. ):

Answer (score 9):

You could simply use `CALayer` to achieve this animation.Try below method.

```
func scaleX() {

    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.scale.x")
    animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgSize: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
    animation.toValue = NSValue(cgSize: CGSize(width: 1.2, height: 1)) 
    animation.duration = 1.0
    self.imageView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "Image-scale")
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.0)

}

func reset() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { 
          self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }

}
```

**Note :** I am using `imageView` to test animation.You can assign your `view` to perform animation.

**Updated:**

I recommend you to use basic UIView animation by changing its frame content size.Try below method.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //To restrict animation repeats.
    resetButton.isEnabled = false
    resetButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true
    scaleButton.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = true 
 }


func scaleX() {

     resetButton.isEnabled = true
     scaleButton.isEnabled = false  
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { 
        self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.imageView.frame.origin.x, y: self.imageView.frame.origin.y, width: self.imageView.frame.width + 100, height: self.imageView.frame.height)
   }
}

func reset() {

    resetButton.isEnabled = false
    scaleButton.isEnabled = true 
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {    
    self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.imageView.frame.origin.x, y: self.imageView.frame.origin.y, width: self.imageView.frame.width  - 100, height: self.imageView.frame.height)       
 }

 }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for response but I want to increment the width of view without changing x coordinate of view and also decrement the width of view without changing the x coordinate.Can you please let me know how can we achieve this by above method.