# Update NSLayoutConstraint animation issue

Tags: ios, swift, animation, nslayoutconstraint

It's a simple test, all codes as below, why lblA has no animation when width changed to 30? but it has animation when width changed to 300.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let lblA = UILabel()
    var lblAWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?
    var tag = false
//  let lblB = UILabel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.lblA.backgroundColor = .red

        self.view.addSubview(self.lblA)
        self.lblA.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|[v]"
            , options: []
            , metrics: nil
            , views: ["v" : self.lblA]))
        self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v]|"
            , options: []
            , metrics: nil
            , views: ["v" : self.lblA]))

        let widthConstraint = self.lblA.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)

        widthConstraint.isActive = true
        self.lblAWidthConstraint = widthConstraint

        //
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapView))

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @objc func tapView() {
        tag = !tag

        self.lblAWidthConstraint?.constant = tag ? 300 : 30

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

**[UPDATE] Finally I found this: [Animating Frame of UILabel smoothly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729596/animating-frame-of-uilabel-smoothly)**

Comment: seems your trailing constraints make issue..

Comment: **Increase width, Label A has no animation** How? You don't have width constraint for label A how are increasing width ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya label A's trailing is equal to label B's leading.

Comment: @ZYiOS Then this should work.  Do you see any log for constraint break or any other

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya No error log. and If I replace the UILabels to UIView, the animation is work well.